# How to improve on using HMS API key in Android source code

Tags: android, api-key, huawei-mobile-services

## About HMS API Key

When using HMS (Huawei Mobile Services), some kits need API key. API key can be get from AppGallery Connect -> [Project Setting] -> [General Information]

[AppGallery Connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR5Ns.png)

## Duplicate definitions of HMS API key in Android source code

Inside source code, API key is usually being used like following.

[Case 1]

MainActivity.kt

```
// For example : private val API_KEY = "CgB6e3x9iW/qiE9l9wAUPK0e/bJQe5uIgTlYUD4bPc8gzjriSVxDDzX2fAVjCVdUHkP+tan0Xi0sf4tj7t11TJJe"
private val API_KEY = "Your API key"

// If using map kit
MapsInitializer.setApiKey(API_KEY)
```

[Case 2]

strings.xml

```
<!-- For example : <string name="api_key">CgB6e3x9iW/qiE9l9wAUPK0e/bJQe5uIgTlYUD4bPc8gzjriSVxDDzX2fAVjCVdUHkP+tan0Xi0sf4tj7t11TJJe</string> -->
<string name="api_key">Your API key</string>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
// If using map kit
MapsInitializer.setApiKey(getString(R.string.api_key))
```

However, these cases have to put API key into source code directly.

Actually, when using HSM, you have to download agconnect-services.json from AppGallery Connect and put it under app folder.

[Android Studio Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcYkH.png)

If you open agconnect-services.json, you can find that API key is already included.

[agconnect-services.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4Pof.png)

There will be duplicate definitions of API key. It is not good for API key management in source code.

## Solution

The best solution is to use the API key in agconnect-services.json directly and do not put another definition into source code. The following is an example.

MainActivity.kt

```
val api_key = AGConnectServicesConfig.fromContext(applicationContext).getString("client/api_key")

// If using map kit
MapsInitializer.setApiKey(api_key)
```

Answer (score 2):

AGConnectServicesConfig is deprecated. You can use this:

```
 val apiKey = AGConnectOptionsBuilder().build(this).getString("client/api_key")
```

to get the key from agconnect-service.json. This might help some one in future

Answer (score 1):

I used map kit recently. I use the map kit version:

```
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:maps:5.1.0.300'
```

It's more simple now.
If agconnect-services.json and *.jks is included and well configured as the huawei official site:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-sdk-config-agc-0000001061560289-V5

The MapsInitializer.setApiKey(api_key) have not be needed to write.

```
//        MapsInitializer.setApiKey("Your API key");
```

The official SDK demo may contains  MapsInitializer.setApiKey("Your API key") in its java code;
Could unline it if agconnect-services.json has be configured.